# ¿Como alinear una imagen en una lista de elementos?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

hola comunidad tengo una duda no se mucho de `bootstrap` quiero alinear una imagen dentro de una lista de elementos pero no se que clases usar o que `css`

este es mi código:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center">Detalles de Artículos Seleccionados</h2>

    <ul class="list-group">

        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <h5 class="mb-1">Productos dentro del Carrito</h5>          
            </div>       
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
            <img src="/Img/confirmedmail.png"/>
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <h5 class="mb-1" style="color:#004B56;">F11407 CINTA DE EMPAQUE TRANSAPARENTE 48MMX50M TP-1060 WESTON</h5>
                <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
                <button class="btn btn-info"><i class="oi oi-cart"></i> Volver a Comprar</button>
            </div>
            <p class="mb-1">CINTA DE EMPAQUE TRANSPARENTE 48mm X 150M ($ x pza, caja c/36)</p>
            <small class="text-muted">$499.10 x 1 unidad</small>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

asi se ve en pantalla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que quede alineada de esta manera, la imagen a la izquierda y el texto a la derecha aun lado de la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He refactorizado bastante tu código utilizando [cards de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/) y utilizando la clase `row no-gutters` para ver qué te parece esta visualización. La puedes personalizar a tu gusto:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center">Detalles de Artículos Seleccionados</h2>
<h5 class="mb-1">Productos dentro del Carrito</h5>
<div class="card">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="card-header">
            <img src="/Img/confirmedmail.png"/>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
                <h5 style="color:#004B56;">F11407 CINTA DE EMPAQUE TRANSAPARENTE 48MMX50M TP-1060 WESTON</h5>
                <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
                <p>CINTA DE EMPAQUE TRANSPARENTE 48mm X 150M ($ x pza, caja c/36)</p>
                <small class="text-muted">$499.10 x 1 unidad</small>
                <button class="btn btn-info"><i class="oi oi-cart"></i> Volver a Comprar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A mi parecer se ve mucho más limpio el código sin usar tantas clases de Bootstrap y es altamente personalizable. Te recomiendo que leas la documentación de las [cards de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/) para que investigues sus posibilidades. Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo si me dio una idea de como hacerlo pero la verdad se movió un poco el diseño al recorrer un ciclo foreach y batalle para ponerle una cabecera y un footer fuera del card pero ya quedo !!